# How to calculate avg of elements which

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm working with `postgres`

I have a table (`tbl`) with the following fields: `name, words`
the fields type are strings)

I need to calculate for each `name` (which is `aaa`) the average percentage of `words` which are not null

I have tried something like:

```
SELECT AVG(COUNT(words is not null) - count(*))
FROM tbl
WHERE name="test"
```

But I got the following error:

```
aggregate function calls cannot be nested
```

I tried to change the query to:

```
SELECT (AVG((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tbl WHERE words IS NOT NULL) - (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tbl))
FROM tbl
WHERE name="test"
```

but it seems that I got wrong values.

For example, for the following table:

```
name,   words 
----------------------------
test    abc test, 1, 2, 3
t2      NULL
test    NULL
t3      NULL
t2      a,b,c,d,e
test    def zxy
t2      NULL
```

the result for `test` need to be `2/3` (because there are 2 results of `test` which are not null and there are 3 `test` in the table)

How can I write the query in the right way ?

Comment: Post sample data and expected results to clarify what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cant nest it,

so go with subquery:

```
SELECT  
1.0*sum((case when a.words is null then 0 else 1 end))/
(SELECT  count(*) FROM tbl b WHERE b.name= a.name group by b.name)
FROM tbl a
WHERE a.name= 'test'
group by name
```

Output:

```
Avg_
0.666666666666
```

Comment: I'm getting array of zeros (0,0,0...) in the result (and it's not ok) it's need to be one value

Comment: I add an example for what the result I expect

Comment: Its corrected, now you get 2/3 as a result 0.6666. let me know

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution:

```
SELECT CAST((CAST((SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM tbl
WHERE name="test" and words IS NOT NULL) as float)/(SELECT COUNT(*)FROM tbl WHERE name="test")) as float) as result
FROM tbl
WHERE name="test"
GROUP BY Country
```